# Generating unqiue Property with default

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

What is the best practice to generate a unique property on a mongodb/mongoose model on creation? That is, what is the most elegant way to check if the generated value isn't already used and to generate another value before saving?

```
let schema = new Schema({
   name: {type: String},
   uniqueProperty: {type: String, unique:true, default:generateUniqueProp} // only works as long as generated Value isn't already in use
})
```

Comment: Is the unique value have to be semantic? If not, then you can use `Date.now()` use the executing time as a unique value, and you get out of the question in the root.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a two step approach?

1. You can use an `update` with `upsert` which doesn't do anything. In this way if the value already exists no object will be created, if it doesn't a new object will be added to the collection.
2. If the object was created add the rest of the data, if it wasn't try again with another value.

Comment: Thank you. This is more a controller-based approach, right? I'd like to stick to the model itself and as native as possible.

Comment: Well that is as native as possible "upsert" is there for that reason. To generate a unique value and be sure to "keep it" you need to lock the DB, and that will kill your performance. A possible solution is having a really low chance of duplicate, using a UUID generator.